# Can Vim autocommand be triggered by filetype instead of by pattern?

Tags: vim, macros, filetype

I know how to set up features using `:autocmd` for specific file extensions:

Eg. **~/.vim/ftplugin/xml.vim**

```
augroup xml
    au BufEnter *.xml call Setup_XML_Menu()
    au BufLeave *.xml call Destroy_XML_Menu()
augroup END
```

Never mind what`Setup_XML_Menu()`does - the point is I'm setting and resetting configuration when I enter or leave an XML buffer.

But is there a way to apply an autocommand for a particular *filetype* instead?

If I enter a buffer named *.xml, the BufEnter autocmd kicks in as I expect.
But I'd like this to happen when I enter *any* buffer that has `filetype=xml`

So if I enter a buffer named server.wsdl (assume I've already arranged for this buffer's filetype to be **xml**), I'd like the XML autocmd to be applied there too, without configuring autocommands for every conceivable XML file extension.

I hoped I could have something like:

```
au BufEnter xml call ...
```

or

```
au BufEnter filetype xml call ...
```

But these don't work (the first example only applies to a buffer named 'xml').

The other possibility I considered: `au FileType xml ...` only applies when I explicitly change the filetype of the buffer - I want the settings to be applied and removed when I hop in and out of particular buffer windows.

Am I asking too much?

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like `au BufEnter * if &ft ==# 'xml' | commands | endif`

Comment: What about `au Filetype xml  commands`?  
Some times `au BufEnter * if &ft` fail, because 'filetype'  does not update untill BufEnter  finishes